# Request for JSON from externel source using $.getjson. 200 success but where is it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get weather data from openweathermap. This url works with coordinates I put in, and I can download the JSON when I input the url the in the browser bar. I'm trying to get this working in my page. When I run this code, in Firebug I can see the HTTP request got the 200 success code, but it's not printing the response for some reason. Am I not using getJSON properly?

```
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat="+ position.coords.latitude +"&lon=" + position.coords.longitude; 

$.getJSON(url, function(res) {
console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to read cross domain JSON in a function which reads JSONP.
Cross domain JSON reading is not possible.

Try a JSONP request instead;, by appending a callback

```
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=" + 
position.coords.latitude +"&lon=" + position.coords.longitude + "&callback=?" ; 

    $.getJSON(url, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    });
```

JSON response is like this :
`{ 'a':22 }`

JSONP response is like :
`myFunction({'a':22} )`  , where myFunction was the value passed as `callback`

jQuery does not need the name of the callback function, however needs `callback` to be mentioned in the URL so that it can indentify it as a JSONP request.

> JSONP
>
> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by
>   the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the
>   discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Append this `?callback=?` to the url and try again like:

```
$.getJSON(url + '?callback=?', function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 function buildQuery() {
     var str = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=27.175009&lon=78.041849";
            return "select * from json where url ='" + str + "' ";
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
            data: {
                q: buildQuery(),
                format: "json"
            },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function (data) {
                consol.log(data);
            }
      });
```

working Demo :-

http://jsfiddle.net/HWuDk/1/