# jquery json call to a api not populating

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to create a really simple json call to the openweather website but nothing is returning when I paste the url into the browser it returns data.

here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
 $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139',function(result){
   document.write(feed);
  });
 });
 });
```

and here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KfwU8/

any help in getting me started would be great!! thanks

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). Once you've included jQuery and fixed the "$ is not defined" error, you'll see that the request is blocked by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Request for JSON from externel source using $.getjson. 200 success but where is it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323603/request-for-json-from-externel-source-using-getjson-200-success-but-where-is)

Answer (score -1):

Create a PHP file (on the same domain):

```
<?php 

$lat = isset($_GET['lat']) ? $_GET['lat'] : '0';
$lon = isset($_GET['lon']) ? $_GET['lon'] : '0';
print file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=" . $lat . "&lon=" . $lon);

?>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
 $.getJSON('http://addressofyourscript.com/?lat=35&lon=139',function(result){
   document.write(result);
  });
 });
 });
```